# Unable to import test module in Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to run tests for my app as described in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/

However, with the minimal example I have shown below, I get an error complaining that:

`RuntimeError: Model class myproject.myapp.models.MyModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Is there some extra configuration I need to make to enable running of tests, or some other mistake that I may have done or forgotten?

**Full stacktrace:**

```
$ ./manage.py test myapp


System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: myproject.myapp.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: myproject.myapp.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/myapp/tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import MyModel
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/myapp/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class MyModel(models.Model):
File "/home/simernes/workspace/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 112, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class myproject.myapp.models.MyModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
    ...
]
```

**apps.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
```

**tests.py:**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import MyModel


# Create your tests here.
class MyModelTests(TestCase):

    def model_names_are_unique(self):
        """
        The database crashes if the same name is registered twice
        :return:
        """
        unique_name = "Unique Name"

        model_first = MyModel(name=unique_identifier)
        model_first.save()

        model_second = MyModel(name=unique_identifier)
        model_second.save()
        self.assertTrue(True)  # todo: assert that an error is raised
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was caused by somehow a `__init__.py` was placed in the root folder of the django project. By deleting this file it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this edit in your 'settings.py' file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myapp',
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. I've tried to re-create my app step by step and with a fresh app I am able to get the test to run, but it seems like somehow the tests get loaded without an app config